# Cannot make subscribe newBlockHeaders work

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

I'm doing this to get all blocks from the network:

```
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new Web3.providers.IpcProvider("...", net));
web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders', function (err, result) {
    ...
}).on('data', function (blockHeader) {
    ...
});
```

but callbacks are never called (except when I shutdown Geth)

Using web3 1.0 and latest Geth on Windows and Linux.

Also tried with web sockets without luck. Is there something else I can try?

Thanks.

Comment: Your syntax looks correct, I would guess that the `IpcProvider` isn't connecting. I put together [this](https://github.com/leopoldjoy/react-ethereum-dapp-example) example repo that successfully uses web3 v1.0. Here's a working example of using websockets to subscribe to `newBlockHeaders`: https://github.com/leopoldjoy/react-ethereum-dapp-example/blob/master/src/containers/MetaCoin/MetaCoin.js#L99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is not to get the result from the `on` event, but get it in the callback:

```
web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders', function (err, result) {
    if(!error) {
        console.log(result); // succcess!
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
let Web3 = require('web3')

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://xxxxxx'))

web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders', function (error, result) {    
    if (!error) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: doesn't work after few minutes